# How to pass change_password.html to replace Django Admin Password Reset

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-authentication

Currently in my urls.py I have the following links for user to reset their password

```
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('password/', user_views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html', success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/change_password.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'),name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

here is the change_password.html

```
        <main class="mt-5" >
            <div class="container dark-grey-text mt-5">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

After the user receives the reset email and clicks on the link to reset password it goes to the Django Admin Style page to reset password.

How can I pass the template that I have `change_password.html` and how can I redirect afterwards to the login page to login?

Just to add more context not sure if it might be the reason in the main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls'), ),
]
```

Here is the terminal showing the sequence:

```
"GET /users/password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1849
"POST /users/password-reset/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /users/password-reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1339
"GET /reset/NTM/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /reset/NTM/set-password/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2288
"POST /reset/NTM/set-password/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1459
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PasswordResetConfirmView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView) and then pass the `template_name` parameter.

To redirect the user to the login page after resetting their password, you can set the `login_url` attribute to the URL of your login page.

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views

app_name = 'users'
..............
    path('login/', MyLoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True, template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('password/', user_views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/change_password.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html', login_url='/any-login-url/'), name='password_reset_complete'),
    .............................
    ...............................
```

### Edit

Try to create a subclass of `PasswordResetConfirmView` so:

```py
# in views.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    post_reset_login = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('any-login-url')
```

With the `post_reset_login` attribute set to True, the user will be automatically logged in after they reset their password, and they will be redirected to the URL specified in the `success_url` attribute.

Then in `urls.py`:

```py
from .views import CustomPasswordResetConfirmView

urlpatterns = [
    # ... 
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', CustomPasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    # ...
]
```

Comment: it is still showing the Django Admin style Change Password Page

Comment: @A_K Try to check it correctly, try to restart the server in another port using `python manage.py runserver 5000` and also try to clear browser cache, it should work.

Comment: yes it should work I have followed the line  PasswordResetConfirmView and even changed the name of the templates to match the documentation but for some reason it is still showing the Django Admin Template. I have cleared the cache and the server but not sure what is the reason for not changing. I have updated the post to show the urls after you answer

Comment: @A_K I think you need to create a subclass so try edited answer.

Comment: I did that just now but still I added the sequence in the terminal for some reason the first part is showing the templates I added while the password-reset-confirm is not taking it. also the confirmation that the password is changed

Comment: @A_K did you also make changes in urls.py? It should work.

Comment: @A_K Can you please tell me that all other templates, which you've provided inside views are working? for instance, `users/password_reset.html` works which is of `PasswordResetView`?

Comment: So I did a work around and moved them to the main urls.py instead of users app now it is working.